# download play 2.7 -unable to find zip folder

Tags: playframework

I am spending lot of time in finding the installable/download link for play 2.7.

for some reason , site is so complex that it never display the link from where I can download.
can someone please help

Comment: You need to install `sbt`

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Requirements

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/NewApplication

Comment: thanks @AndriyKuba . I am just wondering for 2.1 version we used to just install a zip file and export the. Play framework has a inbuild sbt and that take care of it.

Comment: Now it looks opposite :) we have an inbuilt play in sbt. Btw,  the "activator" was removed and discontinued. And ... btw in the more visited section of StackOverflow this question would be "minused" to -5 within a few minutes :)